# Selecting both a hypothesis and Goal while applying a tactic

Tags: coq, tactic

I have a hypothesis `H` and some function `foo`. I want to simplify foo in both `H` and the `Goal`. How do I achieve this with a single tactic?

The tactic `simpl foo in *` selects everything. The tactic `simpl foo` selects only the goal. The tactic `simpl foo in H` only selects `H`.

How do I write `simple foo in H, Goal`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can write `simpl in H |- *`.

For instance:

```
  Goal 2 + 2 = 4 -> 3 + 3 = 6 -> 4 + 4 = 8.
    intros H1 H2.
    simpl in H1 |- *.
```